# Creating a running total for a coin counter

Tags: c#

I'm working on making a running total for a coin calculator we're creating for a school project. It's a C# program running in Visual Studio 2019. Currently, I have it adding total change for a single instance, but I need to add a running total that shows before you end the program.

I've tried looking online, but I cant seem to find code that would fit into what I am making. I'm a beginner with C#, so all my ideas have fallen short. Here is my code; hopefully someone can help me out. (Note that the running total should go into the `while` statement when the user enters `N`.)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalcChange
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string choice;
            int q, d, n, p, hd;
            int totchange, totcents, dollars, cents;

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Change Calculator");

            Console.Write("Do you have change? (y/n): ");
            choice = Console.ReadLine();

            while (choice.Equals("Y", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                hd = getCoin("Helf Dollars");
                q = getCoin("Quarters");
                d = getCoin("Dimes");
                n = getCoin("Nickels");
                p = getCoin("Pennies");

                totcents = (hd * 50) + (q * 25) + (d * 10) + (n * 5) + p;
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou have " + totcents + " Cents.");

                dollars = totcents / 100;
                cents = totcents % 100;
                Console.WriteLine("Which is " + dollars + " dollars and "
                                    + cents + " cents.\n");

                Console.WriteLine("I'm in the loop!");

                Console.Write("Do you have more change? (y/n): ");
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            while (choice.Equals("N", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {

            }

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.Write("Press any key to Continue...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        } //end of main

        static int getCoin(string cointype)
        {
            int ccount;

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.Write("How many " + cointype + " do you have?");
                    ccount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (ccount < 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Coin amounts cannot be negative, please re-enter a valid amount.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Illegal input: " + ex.Message + " please re-enter a valid amount.");
                    ccount = -1;
                }
            } while (ccount < 0);

            return ccount;
        }
    } //end of class
}
```

Comment: Try to explain to me what a running total is

Comment: Is running total a total for all the times the input was Y?

Comment: What do you mean by "single instance" when you say "*Currently i have it adding total change for a single instance*"? How does that differ from what you are expecting?

Comment: So when you run the program it asks if you have change. when you say yes it then asks for how many of each coin you have and then gives the total based on the inputs. after it gives the total it asks again you again if you have change. when you say yes the cycle repeats until you give a no response. Once you respond no it needs to give a grand total of all different iterations so lets say i had 75 cents the first time and then the second time i had 28. if i decide i dont have any more change then it should tell me that my grand total is 101 cents or a dollar and 1 cent.

Comment: so the running total is all the different loops added together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well just keep a variable that will sum all iterations

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CalcChange
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string choice;
            int q, d, n, p, hd;
            int totchange, totcents, dollars, cents;
            int grandTotal = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Change Calculator");

            Console.Write("Do you have change? (y/n): ");
            choice = Console.ReadLine();

            while (choice.Equals("Y", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                hd = getCoin("Helf Dollars");
                q = getCoin("Quarters");
                d = getCoin("Dimes");
                n = getCoin("Nickels");
                p = getCoin("Pennies");

                totcents = (hd * 50) + (q * 25) + (d * 10) + (n * 5) + p;
                Console.WriteLine("\nYou have " + totcents + " Cents.");

                // once the user puts his change add the total cents to the grandtotal
                // variable
                grandTotal += totcents;
                dollars = totcents / 100;
                cents = totcents % 100;
                Console.WriteLine("Which is " + dollars + " dollars and "
                                    + cents + " cents.\n");

                Console.WriteLine("I'm in the loop!");

                Console.Write("Do you have more change? (y/n): ");
                choice = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            while (choice.Equals("N", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {

            }

            // here print the value
            Console.WriteLine($"You have a total of {grandTotal / 100} dollars and {grandTotal % 100} cents");

            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Console.Write("Press any key to Continue...");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        } //end of main

        static int getCoin(string cointype)
        {
            int ccount;

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.Write("How many " + cointype + " do you have?");
                    ccount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (ccount < 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Coin amounts cannot be negative, please re-enter a valid amount.");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Illegal input: " + ex.Message + " please re-enter a valid amount.");
                    ccount = -1;
                }
            } while (ccount < 0);

            return ccount;
        }
    } //end of class
}
```

I added some comments in the code for more clarity

Hope this helps

Comment: alright so that works and i understand why it works so thanks a ton! The only issue is when i run it the grand total keeps being posted over and over again as opposed to just one time

Comment: The grand total is printed before the program terminates, so im not sure what do you mean by _being poster over and over again_. Also, if the answer works for you, you can accept the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: You could make it as simple as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60071917/10216583) using the [Math.DivRem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.divrem?view=netframework-4.8) method.